# GridBagLayout don't order my elements

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to do a simple graphic app but I'm having some problems with the GridBagLayout.
I want to have a label that introduces the title of the app and just under the title, I want to have a text field. The problem is, even if I put some `.gridweight` and `.gridx` (and others), the program don't want to give these attributes to my elements.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Logiciel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("The Genius of Numbers");
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        content.add(label1, constraints);

        JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField("Console");
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.gridwidth = 4;
        constraints.gridheight = 3;
        content.add(textfield1, constraints);

        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.setSize(600, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: You set the layout to be GridBag on the **old** content pane, that you are then replacing. Try setting the layout on the `content` panel, rather than the frame.

Comment: `content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` Did you even read the Javadoc for the classes and methods you are using?

Comment: Still not working. And yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ordous said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511590/gridbaglayout-dont-order-my-elements#comment39825295_25511590) replace this line:

```
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

for this one:

```
content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

And you might want to add:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

So your program would end and not keep the thread alive.

It will look like this:

[image]